How to remove padding in details view in Windows 10
How do you remove the padding in Windows 10? On Windows 7 you could do it by editing ExplorerFrame.dll but the one in Windows 10 is a binary with no editable XML.
This is what I'm talking about:
http://www.sevenforums.com/customization/45276-possible-change-list-item-height-spacing.html
I searched everywhere for answers and I will be humbled if I somehow missed it.

Finally debugged this to answer my own question.
It's located in C:\Windows\SystemResources\ExplorerFrame.dll.mun
Open it with Resource Hacker, it has a UIFile with a resource called 40960. It's binary but the XML data is unicode plaintext. The culprit that controls the padding is the last instance of 22rp located near the end of the file.
rect(0rp, 0rp, 0rp, 0rp) 22rp middleleft|endellipsis|editcontrol themeable(dtb(ItemsView, 6, 1)
Changing that to 01rp removes the padding and gives a nice compact view, though I believe you only have to change it to about 17 for the same result.
